# Create a numpy array (10x1) with zeros and fives

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a 10x1 numpy array with the number 5 in the first 3 elements and the other 7 elements with the number 0. Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest would seem to be:

```
import numpy as np

the_array = np.array([5]*3 + [0]*7)
```

Does this simple approach present some specific disadvantage for your purposes?

Of course there are many alternatives, such as

```
the_array = np.zeros((10,))
the_array[:3] = 5
```

If you need to repeat this specific operation a huge number of times, so small differences in speed matter, you could benchmark various approaches to see where a nanosecond or so might be saved.  But the premise is so unlikely I would not suggest doing that for this specific question, even though I'm a big fan of `timeit`:-).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! When I printed the shape of the_array it was (75,). So to get it to the shape (75,1). I used np.reshape(the_array, (75,1)). Thanks again!

Comment: Alex, this is very helpful, I'm just learning about numpy, this is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way proposed by Alex Martelli is the clearest but here's another alternative using `np.repeat` which can be quite useful for constructing arrays with repeating values:

```
>>> np.repeat([5, 0], [3, 7])
array([5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

So here, a list of values `[5, 0]` is passed in along with a list of repeats `[3, 7]`. In the returned NumPy array the first element of the values list, `5`, is repeated `3` times and the second element `0` is repeated `7` times.

Comment: Great all numpy solution. You can translate the OP's request 'number 5 in the first 3 elements and the other 7 elements with the number 0' with zip:  `np.repeat(*zip([5,3],[0,7]))` -- which seems more natural to me...

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following.

`import numpy as np`

`arr = np.zeros(10)`

`arr[:3] = 5`

Answer (score 0):

Both Alex and ajcr have useful answers but one thing to keep in mind is what your expected data type needs are.

np.zeros for example will cast a float whereas the other two answers will cast an int.

You can of course recast by using the 'astype' method:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat([5,0],[3,7]).reshape(10,1)
```

Comment: can you please add more description to this answer ?

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros(10)
print("An array of zeros : ")
print (array)

array = np.ones(10)
print("An array of ones : ")
print (array)

array = np.ones(10)*5
print("An array of fives : ")
print (array)
```